# Xcode thinks delegate method is actually a new method being declared

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, methods, delegates

I just created a new utility application from the Xcode templates and I have a problem with the `- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller` method not being called. When I use the three finger tap on the trackpad to define it, it says that method is defined in MainViewController.m when it is definitely in the protocol of Flip.

MainVC.h

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *flipsidePopoverController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *backgroundView;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.jpg"]];
    _backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View Controller

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    //width
    if (controller.widthSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        //number of icons

    } else {
        //icon space
    }

    NSLog(@"b"); // not called
    [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
        UIPopoverController *popoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        self.flipsidePopoverController = popoverController;
        self.flipsidePopoverController.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (IBAction)togglePopover:(id)sender
{
    if (self.flipsidePopoverController) {
        [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlternate" sender:sender];
    }
}

@end
```

FlipVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FlipsideViewController;

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *widthSegmentedControl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *widthNumberOfIcons;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *widthIconSpace;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *heightSegmentedControl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *heightNumberOfIcons;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *heightIconSpace;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface FlipsideViewController ()

@end

@implementation FlipsideViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"a"); //this is called
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}

@end
```

There are two NSLogs in there, one for the method where the done button gets pressed (a) and one for the one where that didFinish method should be called (b). The problem is that when I press the done button on the Flip controller nothing happens (although "a" gets logged).

Comment: I wonder does it go in if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {}

Comment: Interesting. That prepare for segue method runs but the code inside that if doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I removed the default button bar Info item and replace it with a normal button. The problem is that the segue needs to be anchored to that button and connected to the togglePopover   method in the MainViewController.m file.